# Inline instantiation of a constant List

Tags: c#, .net

I try to do something like this:

```
public const List<String> METRICS = new List<String>()
        {
            SourceFile.LOC,
            SourceFile.MCCABE,
            SourceFile.NOM,
            SourceFile.NOA,
            SourceFile.FANOUT,
            SourceFile.FANIN,
            SourceFile.NOPAR,
            SourceFile.NDC,
            SourceFile.CALLS
        };
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
FileStorer.METRICS' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109805/declaring-a-const-double-in-c

Comment: NOTE: Closing this question as a duplicate was a mistake. The linked question is about **constant arrays**, this question is about **constant lists**. Although both approaches provide roughly the same functionality, they are different and the answers are different. Only answers to this question mention `ReadOnlyCollection`. Questions are related, but neither is duplicate of another.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`const` is for compile-time constants. You *could* just make it `static readonly`, but that would only apply to the `METRICS` variable itself (which should typically be Metrics instead, by [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)). It wouldn't make the *list* immutable - so someone could call `METRICS.Add("shouldn't be here");`

You may want to use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to wrap it. For example:

```
public static readonly IList<String> Metrics = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>
    (new List<String> { 
         SourceFile.LoC, SourceFile.McCabe, SourceFile.NoM,
         SourceFile.NoA, SourceFile.FanOut, SourceFile.FanIn, 
         SourceFile.Par, SourceFile.Ndc, SourceFile.Calls });
```

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` just wraps a potentially-mutable collection, but as nothing else will have access to the `List<T>` afterwards, you can regard the overall collection as immutable.

(The capitalization here is mostly guesswork - using fuller names would make them clearer, IMO.)

Whether you declare it as `IList<string>`, `IEnumerable<string>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` or something else is up to you... if you expect that it should only be treated as a sequence, then `IEnumerable<string>` would probably be most appropriate. If the order matters and you want people to be able to access it by index, `IList<T>` may be appropriate. If you want to make the immutability apparent, declaring it as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` could be handy - but inflexible.

Comment: i came here looking for the `new List<string>{ ... }` part. Thanks Jon :)

Comment: I suppose there's a reason, but to me it's odd that `ReadOnlyCollection` implements `IList<>` as that exposes `.Add`

Answer (score 31):

You'll need to use a `static` `readonly` list instead. And if you want the list to be immutable then you might want to consider using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`.

```
private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _metrics =
    new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new[]
        {
            SourceFile.LOC,
            SourceFile.MCCABE,
            SourceFile.NOM,
            SourceFile.NOA,
            SourceFile.FANOUT,
            SourceFile.FANIN,
            SourceFile.NOPAR,
            SourceFile.NDC,
            SourceFile.CALLS
        });

public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> Metrics
{
    get { return _metrics; }
}
```