# Initilize an array of struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, initialization

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to initialize array of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079206/how-to-initialize-array-of-struct)
>   [Initializing an Array of Structs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309496/initializing-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

C#, Visual studio 2010

I want declare an array of struct and initialize it on the same time but can not get it right
How do i write to default initialize an array consisting of structs ?

The following wont go through the compiler but show the idea of what I want to archive

```
    private struct PrgStrTrans_t
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string fname;
    }

    private PrgStrTrans_t[] PrgStrTrans = { {1, "hello", "there"}, {2, "Fun", thisone"}}
```

Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your struct, and put `new PrgStrTrans(...),` on each line of the array.

Like this:

```
private struct PrgStrTrans_t
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string fname;

    public PrgStrTrans_t(int i, string n, string f)
    {
        id = i;
        name = n;
        fname = f;
    }
}

private PrgStrTrans_t[] PrgStrTrans = {
                                          new PrgStrTrans_t(4, "test", "something"),
                                          new PrgStrTrans_t(2, "abcd", "1234")
                                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private PrgStrTrans_t[] PrgStrTrans = { new PrgStrTrans_t() { id = 1, name = "hello", fname = "there"},new PrgStrTrans_t() {id = 2, name = "Fun", fname = "thisone"}};
```

It would be better if you made a constructor, that would avoid typing the property names.