# Initialize an array of struct in C#

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0

First of all, this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7079206/6156470) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309496/6156470). I am not looking for answers taking the form of

```
Some_struct[] struct_array = new[]{
    Some_struct(parameters),
    Some_struct(parameters),
    ...
}
```

with Some_struct has a parameterized constructor.

The array to be created is large in size. Is there a way that one can initialize the array all at once without iterating over its indexes and explicitly initializing each data member?

Comment: _"explicitly each data member"_ missing the predicate

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass parameters you need a constructor. Otherwise you can simply use:

```
var array = new Some_struct[1000000];
```

Since structs are value types, they are all initialized with the default values.

```
Some_struct s = array[4711]; // never null
```