# Why const mytype _var = new mytype() doesn't work?

Tags: c#, constants

I'm very curious looking for an explanation why the following code isn't allowed in C#.NET designer:

```
const foo f = new foo();
```

It give the following error message:

> 'f' is of type 'ConsoleApplication1.foo'. A const field of a reference
>   type other than string can only be initialized with null.

The question is: Why? Can someone explain this `const` requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked at least 10 times. Please search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a const double\[\] in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109805/declaring-a-const-double-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a `const` must be something that can be resolved at **Compile Time**.

`new foo();` will be executed at **runtime**.

You probably want to use the `readonly` keyword to ensure that it cannot be initialised outside of the constructors:

```
private readonly foo f = new foo();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'II accept it in 6minutes.

Comment: Since the error text does not include a containing type before the name `f`, I'm really sure what the Original Poster really has is a local variabel, and *not* a field. Therefore, saying `private` or `readonly` is not allowed in that context.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen If that's the case, then he probably wouldn't have accepted the post as it wouldn't have fixed his problem.

Comment: @Servy Maybe so. Maybe "ConsoleApplication1" was not the place his actual problem came up, but only a sandbox he made for testing it. But I'm sure the compiler error text he quotes comes from a local variable, because were it a (static or instance) field, the compiler would have included the namespace-qualified type name in the very beginning of the message.

Answer (score 3):

Because a `const` in C# must be a *compile-time* constant.  Thus, the only valid `const` option (for most reference types) is `null`.

The one exception is `string` where you can assign it to a string literal.

```
// allowed because string literals are compile-time
private const string Message = "Hello World";
```

You can have a `readonly` field, which will allow the field to be set only in the initializer or constructor.  In essence this is like a `const` except it is determined at run-time and can be `static` or instance (all `const` fields are `static` automatically).

However, one should note that a `readonly` reference just means that the *reference* is read-only, this does not mean the object it *refers* to is also read-only (unless, of course, the object is immutable by design, like `string`).

For example:

```
private readonly List<string> validStrings = new List<string> { "Apple", "Orange", "Pear" };
```

Even though `validStrings` above is `readonly`, it only means you can't change `validStrings` by assigning it to a new reference.  **But** you *can* modify what it refers to if the object is mutable:

```
// allowed, you can change what it refers to
validStrings.Clear();

// disallowed, cannot change what the reference refers to outside of constructor
validStrings = new List<string> { "Other", "Stuff" };
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks again for you explanation! I would + 1 if I could.

Comment: @Jack: No problem, I'm just curious why someone else must have downvoted it without an explanation as to why...

Answer (score 3):

const indicates that the value is known at compile time. Because new allocates an object (which is impossible if the program is not running), you cannot set a const to a new object. you can achieve something somewhat simmilar like this:

```
static readonly Foo foo = new Foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the error text is confusing because it's a local variable (declared inside a method) you have, and not a field (declared outside methods, belonging to a class (or struct)).

You must remove `const` because, as others say, it's not usefull for reference types other than `string`.